# c# accessing ui elements in Task without using dispatcher

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm hoping to find a mechanism for accessing/manipulating a ui element (like textbox) properties in a separate Thread but accessing it using Dispatcher means giving control to UI thread which keeps the user from doing anything (which is something I don't want - to freeze ui..)

So I actually want to access the ui from a separate thread without needing to freeze the main UI thread.

Comment: Using the Dispatcher is exactly what you want to be doing, as far as I can see. As long as you make sure you're not overloading the UI thread with millions of rapid updates, it shouldn't freeze it.

Comment: i have to access a lot of ui elements and do operations on it.. so they are not millions but yes they are enough to hold user to do anything or make UI thread super sluggish which i dont want...

Comment: There are a few workarounds for these kinds of issues, such as the ones here: http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/wpf-high-speed-mvvm/

Comment: That is exactly what the dispatcher is for. _access a lot of ui elements and do operations on it_ Do the operations in the background, post the result to the ui on the dispatcher.

Comment: You can't modify the UI from another thread and that's that. You never could. That goes all the way back to Windows 95. Other OSs and windowing systems have the **same** restrictions.

Comment: What is your actual problem and why do you think you need to modify the UI from many threads?  What **exactly** is taking too long? Do you use inefficient UI code? Are you trying to load 10000 rows in a data grid that can only display 50 rows at a time? Are you *blocking* the UI while waiting for data to come from the database?

Comment: The first step to display a lot of data on a UI is to **not** do it. That's why grids offer paging, virtualized data and scrolling. Why load everything if the user can only view one page at a time? You can even hide the paging behaviour by loading the next page when the user tries to scroll.

Comment: Another technique is to *avoid* modifying individual controls. Use data binding, especially in WFP. This way, instead of forcing each control to redraw itself when you modify it, you modify the data and the controls update themselves. That's how MVVM works

Comment: Another technque is to disable UI updating while you modify many controls. This way the UI gets updated only once, after you finish all modifications

Comment: Check Stephen Cleary's [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) MSDN Magazine article

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access the dependency properties of UI elements on another thread. It is not allowed.

However updating a text property is blindingly fast and that is most likely not your bottleneck. Calculating what the value of that text property is may be slow. So for example if you have an event triggered from the UI you can spawn a task which will run on another thread and keep the UI responsive.

When the value is ready the code on the left hand side of the await will run on the UI thread and you can then modify any UI properties you wish.

```
SomeEvent += async (s,e) => {

   var text = await Task.Run(()=>{
    return SomeVeryExpensiveOperation();          
   });

   MyTextBox.Text = text;

}
```

A more worked out example is here

http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/11/csharp-5-async-and-await-example.html#.WLhBlm_ysUE

Answer (score -3):

In your case, you have to use `static` `class` with `static events`, fire events from your `Task` and handle the event in your `ViewModel / Codebehind`, and do whatever you want in that `event handler`.